# How do I display the form in a template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import *
from .forms import *
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    form = TaskForm()    
    context = {'tasks':tasks, How do I display the value of a Django form field in a template?'form':forms}
    return render(request, 'tasks/list.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length =200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import *

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title','complete')
```

I would like form fields to add new tasks for my todo beginner project.

I use `{{form}}` on the html file but Django display `<module 'django.forms' from '/home/***/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/__init__.py'>` instead of tasks fields

How to get the form in the template ?

Comment: Forms and Models are not the same. This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63876326/django-python-post-method-not-writing-to-database/63876644#63876644

Answer (score -1):

please follow the Django documentation about templates it tells you how to crate templates read it carefully. I mention you the link
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/